# How can I highlight the navbar section above when scrolling to a specific section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a dynamic navbar that scrolls to the section I clicked on, however, I would like to highlight the section in the navbar above when scrolling to the section, but it seems complicated for me. what is wrong with my code? what am I missing?

```
HTML:
```

## Landing Page

### Section 1

### Section 2

### Section 3

### Section 4

```
<script src="JS/src.js"></script>
```

```
JavaScript:
const navBarMenu = document.getElementById('navbar__list');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link');

const createNewList= function () {

let creatingSections = '';    
 
for (section of sections){
    const referencing = section.id;
    const namingReferencing = section.dataset.nav;


    creatingSections += `<li><a class="menu__link" href="#${referencing}" >${namingReferencing}</a></li>`;
}

navBarMenu.innerHTML = creatingSections;
};

createNewList();

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    sections.forEach(function(active){

    if (active.getBoundingClientRect().y >= -400 && active.getBoundingClientRect().y <=150){
        active.classList.add('your-active-class');
    }

    else{
        active.classList.remove('your-active-class');
    }

});
```

});

Comment: Your HTML is missing, or rather not loaded as code. This link should help you put your code into your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You may find IntersectionObserver helpful - it will tell you when an element is visible (or partially visible) in the viewport without your having to do calculations.